# Anime where guy has been hiding for all his life, is caught stealing food, and attends an academy for piloting mech suits

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been trying to think of the title but it's an anime where a guy has been hiding most of his life and using this training simulation pod thing but when he goes to steal food he is caught by the authority and attends an academy type deal for piloting mech suits.

Comment: Why did you delete this post? We don't delete questions just because they've been answered, and answered ID questions can be very useful to future searchers.

Answer (score 14):

This is **Knights of Sidonia**. [Here is the relevant summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Knights_of_Sidonia_episodes) for episode 1:

> Deep within the massive spaceship Sidonia, having exhausted his last supplies of food, Nagate Tanikaze ventures outside his underground shelter to look for food when he is spotted and captured by local security while trying to steal rice. Believing that his life is in danger, Nagate manages to escape the hospital where he is being treated, but is apprehended by some military cadets. One of the cadets, Shizuka Hoshijiro, accompanies Nagate while he is being questioned by the police, when a man called Ochiai appears and takes him to Captain Kobayashi, the highest authority of Sidonia. Kobayashi then proposes that she becomes Nagate's Gardes, on the condition that Tanikaze enters Sidonia's Gardes pilot training program, to which he agrees.